# Pass data from Native C binary to Android app

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a standalone binary file (compiled for Android and was written in C) that can access lower level GPIO and UART ports.

I want to pass the data grabbed by such a binary to an Android app.

Is there a way to do this in Android ?

Edit-1: Let me narrow down my questions. I learned that Android has Binder for IPC mechanism. How can binder be used for IPC communication from Native C/C++ application to Android app ?

Comment: If your binary can execute `am` (the activity manager), it could use that to send an Intent to your app, with the data as an intent extra.

Comment: You might want to explain the environment you are running (stock or custom Android ROM). And what needs to be invoked when, and/or explain why an Android app perhaps running a service calling into the C code isn't sufficient.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I made an edit to the question. Please have a look at it. To asnwer your question, I am only using the AOSP source code on my embedded board. I want to pass some parameters such as data on UART, data on I2C etc to my android application that will be running on the board itself.

Comment: Two paths for investigation: 1) Look at the source code for Android Things [PeripheralManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/peripheralmanager/) which handles the GPIO on that platform version. 2) Older documentation/presentation on [Embedded Android](https://www.opersys.com/downloads/cc-slides/embedded-android/embedded-android-120203.pdf)